# A composition of a periodic function that is somehow not periodic.

Tags: integration, periodic-functions

Is there some g for which g(x mod 1) is not periodic? If so, please tell me what it is.

Comment: "Proof theory", despite the generic name, is a specific field of logic.

Comment: "Basically, my problem is that I am very very sure this is true." I agree, that is a problem. :)

Comment: I second @Rahul: *why* are you very very sure?

Comment: Your conjecture on $f$ and $g$ is unclear. Is that $xf(x)=(\int f)+g(f(x))$ or $xf(x)=\int (f+g(f))$?

Comment: @user254665 It would be the former - note the position of the "$dx$." To the OP: does "$*$" mean multiplication, or [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I linked to the definition of the term when I used the word (note that it's in blue as opposed to black; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition if the link isn't working for you). Convolution of functions is a very important operation, especially in the context of integration, and is universally denoted by "$*$", while "$\cdot$" is reserved for multiplication. It is in fact bad practice to use "$*$" for multiplication when talking about integration, for exactly this reason.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Re: context, you don't have to if you don't want to I suppose, but it only helps. Besides providing more motivation for people to answer the question, if you provide the context behind why you think some fact ought to hold when it does not, that might be helpful for coming up with the "right" version of the conjecture. Also, I was just genuinely interested.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck FWIW "$\cdot$" and "$*$" are certainly different in math, regardless of their roles in computer science. I've rarely seen "$*$" used for multiplication after high school - math texts tend to use $\cdot$ instead, or juxtaposition "$xf(x)$". (Also, I didn't assume you meant convolution - I *asked which you meant*, since I didn't know.) Which isn't to say you shouldn't use it for multiplication - most of the time it is clear what is meant - but when you're talking about re-shaping integration, it's reasonable to suspect that convolution is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may already know this, but I want to write it out in detail - here is a counterexample to your conjecture:

Let $f(x)=(x$ mod $1)-{1\over 2}$. Note that $f$ is periodic of period $1$, *and so is its integral*: $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^{b+1}f(x)dx$, since $\int_b^{b+1}f(x)dx=0$ for all $b$.

Similarly, by what I wrote below, $g\circ f$ is periodic of period $1$ for all functions $g$.

But $xf(x)$ is *not* periodic - one way to see this is to note that $xf(x)$ is bounded on every bounded interval, but is unbounded in general (for $z$ a positive integer, we have $({3\over 4}+z)f({3\over 4}+z)>{z\over 4}$ which goes to infinity as $z\rightarrow\infty$).

So there is no $g$ such that $xf=(\int f)+g\circ f$, since otherwise $xf$ would be periodic as it is the sum of two periodic functions with the same period.

---

**There is no such $g$.**

In general, if $f$ is periodic with period $a$ and $g$ is *any* function, then $g\circ f$ is periodic with period $a$, since $$(g\circ f)(x+a)=g(f(x+a))=g(f(x))=(g\circ f)(x).$$

---

EDIT: the OP asks in a comment about infinite compositions, and infinite sums. The result still holds, and the key fact is the following:

> If $h=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}g_i$ (that is, $h$ is the pointwise limit of the $g_i$s), and each $g_i$ is periodic with period $a$, then $h$ is periodic with period $a$.

*Proof*: $$h(x+a)=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}g_i(x+a)=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}g_i(x)=h(x).$$

How is this relevant? Well, let $g$ be arbitrary, and $f$ have period $a$. Then $g^\infty\circ f=\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}g\circ g\circ g\circ . . .\circ g\circ f$. Well, by the fact above the fold + induction, each $g^n\circ f$ is periodic with period $a$; so $g^\infty\circ f$ is the pointwise limit of periodic-with-period-$a$ functions, hence has period $a$. Similarly for infinite series.

(Now maybe you don't define infinite compositions via pointwise limits; in that case, how *do* you define them?)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Those also, if I understand what you mean correctly. E.g. for any $g$, the function "$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(g^n\circ f)$" is periodic with period $a$. This is because, in general, every finite composition is periodic with period $a$ (by induction), and the pointwise limit of period-with-period-$a$ functions is periodic with period $a$. Similarly for infinite series.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck No. However, I suspect that what you are thinking of allows *stretchings* of $\sin$ and $\cos$ - e.g. $\sin(3x)$ instead of $\sin(x)$ - and, since the periods are different, we can get different phenomena.

Comment: I suspected there was no such $g$ on the grounds that if $f$ and g were differentiable then $f'(x)(\; x-g'(f(x))\;)=0$ for all $x.$ But then  $[x\ne y \land  f(x)=f(y) \land f'(x)\ne 0\ne f'(y)] \implies x=y.$

Comment: That since it can't hold for differentiable f,g, that  I thought there might be a  general counter-example. But I didn't work on it